# Connect to MySQL database from Android

Tags: php, android

I followed a tutorial to connect to a MySQL database through a PHP Script from an Android Application. My problem is (from LogCat): "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select' of undefined at null:1". I had success some time ago, so perhaps I inadvertently modified something that caused this? In my database, there are 4 columns and everything is okay on this side. Here is my PHP code:

```
 <?php

 $host="xxxxx"; // Host name 
 $username="xxxxx"; // Mysql username 
 $password="xxxxx"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="xxxxx"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="xxxxx"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select databse.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE pass>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

 print(json_encode($output));

 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

...and on Android:

```
        String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","Pass1"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://MyWebsite/queryfromandroid.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getString("password")

                    );
            }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try invoking your php script from a browser - this will show you any errors in the script.  Fix those first, then proceed to fix the android side of things.

Comment: Now many SO users have just seen your database information, nice one! I would recommend changing.

Comment: Sorry , but i cant access on Error Log in my Free Hosting Plan , & LogCat , there is only this Error , Nothing else ...

Comment: @Darryl ??????? i will , this is just for Testing Purpose

Comment: Thanks for the Tips , i have an Error : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /srv/disk11/1121827/www/SiteName.com/queryfromandroid.php on line 14
null @Aleks G

Comment: @Nikita Testing purposes or not.. You don't want anyone to gain access to your database.

Comment: yes , i edited my Code and will Delete the DB

Comment: Post your detailed LogCat output. Just copy the whole error form the LogCat and paste.

Comment: i have a new Error on LogCat : 02-22 16:36:48.189: E/log_tag(18899): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray  @swayam , i just have these 2 Errors

Comment: Tried this Script with Html Form , and the Result look Okay when i enter the Correct Pass ...

Comment: `Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray` means that your server is somehow returning a null value.

Comment: yes , i dont know why ... my tab is Correct , all Informations are Correct ...

Comment: The error is in your PHP, clearly.  I strongly discourage you from using `mysql_` functions.  Change to PDO instead - it's easier to use, safer and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , thx also for the Security Flaw Message , i will take a look at PDO

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all , but i Fixed my problem , a tiny small Error is always responsible for these kind of Bug Hard to Detect , here the Code i have modified , in the Php Script :

i replaced this :

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE pass>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
```

by this :

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE pass='".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
```

this > by this =